# Editable item on Primefaces p:orderList

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

Dears, I have the following code:

```
<p:orderList value="#{admProductView.images}" class="NewProductImageList MarTop10" controlsLocation="none" itemValue="#{npimg}" var="npimg" responsive="true" converter="#{imageConverter}" rendered="#{not empty admProductView.images}">
  <p:column class="TexAlCenter" style="width: 100px">
    <h:graphicImage value="#{configView.MR.concat(npimg.fileName)}" class="ImageBorder Wid90" />
  </p:column>
  <p:column class="TexAlCenter">
    <p:inputText class="Wid90" value="#{npimg.label}" placeholder="#{msg.label}" />
  </p:column>
  <p:column class="TexAlCenter" style="width: 30px">
    <p:commandButton icon="fa fa-remove White" class="BlueTextButton RaisedButton Fright MarRight20" actionListener="#{admProductView.deleteImage}" title="#{msg.delete}" update="imageList" process="@this">
      <f:param name="delimg" value="#{npimg.id}" />
    </p:commandButton>
  </p:column>
</p:orderList>
```

The problemn is that the element npimg is being resolved to null on p:inputText line. If I remove the line everything works perfectly.

Glassfish 4.1.1

Mojarra 2.2.12

Primefaces 5.3